# Location address and google play services

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to displaying nearby location address using:
**geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),loc.getLongitude(), 2)**
But unable to retrieve location in my app same as google map .
What is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Just want to know is there any effect on result when google play service not available.

Comment: Yes you need them. see my updated answer.

Comment: can you plz post your code with log cat

Comment: Thanks all .......  Actually i got my solution.Using maps api of different location provider like foursquare or google place api,i can display location.Just need to parse the response from the respective server.

Answer (score 0):

Please install **google play services** from **google play store** in order to get the things done that you are trying for. The services are free to get it installed in your android device.
You also need to have a **google account configured** in order to use those services properly.

Comment: I am not getting error the problem is that in googl map i am able to see 10 location where in my app i able to see one or two location not same as google map.